# Solr/Javascript/Python: open source Solr UI with multiple select faceting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, solr, facet

Are there any open source Solr UI's that support selecting multiple facet values ("OR" faceting)? For example allowing a user to select "red" or "blue" for the facet field "Color".

I'd prefer libraries in javascript/jquery or Python. I know about ajax-solr but it doesn't seem to support multiple selects.

Thanks.

Comment: hey, you'd ask this alreay on the ml :-) this is not such a difficult task if the ajax solr project does not suport this because you can add local parameters to all facets and filter queries. Let me know if you need more info about this

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg44257.html

Answer (score 0):

ajax-solr allows for OR faceting (it lets you do anything Solr can do), you just need to set your tag and ex local parameters. It came up on the ajax-solr mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/ajax-solr/browse_frm/thread/daa36e2d543ada28/6a3fe1ed5db3f077?lnk=gst&q=tag+ex#6a3fe1ed5db3f077